# Switching power supply (SMPS) for servo motors

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, servo

I would like to find a switching power supply to power one [ClearPath servo motor](https://www.teknic.com/model-info/CPM-MCVC-3441S-RLN/?model_voltage=48VDC). I am aware that SMPS is not recommended for servos, but I don't need power for fast deceleration/acceleration. Beyond current/voltage requirements, I am a bit baffled as to how to find a reliable SMPS that can handle some regen power. Hopefully someone can provide some insights.

Comment: Have you considered asking the manufacturer of that industrial servomotor for a recommendation?

Comment: You could always add a a power absorber circuit so that the SMPS doesn't have to handle the backflow of power itself. I don't know much about them, just that they exist. Could just be a cap with a breakdown device for all I know.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In their FAQ Teknic advises against using any switching type power supply that is not specifically designed for servo motors. They told me a SMPS might work for my application but did not give any recommendation.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the suggestion! I found something like that:https://www.applied-motion.com/products/accessories/rc880:)

Comment: @YumekaMengjiaLYU Glad you found something. Sounds like (and priced as if) it is an active device rather than a passive clamp. I wonder what mechanism it is using to clamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always add a a power absorber circuit so that the SMPS doesn't have to handle the backflow of power itself. I don't know much about them, just that they exist. Could just be a cap with a breakdown device for all I know.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your power supply comments.  It looks like you may have already reached out directly to a Teknic Engineer and received some feedback in regard to your power supply question.

Needless to say sizing and choosing the correct power supply for an application is not a simple task and is actually much more involved then most realize.

Here is a link to a helpful technical article on how best to choose and size the right power supply for your application: https://www.teknic.com/selecting-power-supply/

Hopefully this helps make your decision a bit easier!

If you have any other questions please feel free to call us at (585)784-7454, or use our "Contact Us" form online (https://www.teknic.com/contact/).

Best regards,

Mark D. - Teknic Servo Systems Engineer

Comment: Welcome :-) Since the original question was about a product from the company you represent, you do disclose your link to the company, and the power supply-related link is relevant, I *won't* flag this as spam (something which we guard against here). Please be careful not to be seen as excessively promoting the company on unrelated topics. *But* the technical content here is effectively a "link only answer", and as explained in [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) on Meta.SE, an answer which just points elsewhere is "not an answer". Can you edit it to add more technical value?